# How can I append 2 BIG images using Marvin java library(or any other free lib)?

Tags: java, image-processing, javax.imageio, marvin-framework

I have 2 jpegs, about 16 000 x 24 000 px. I have to rotate the second and append it on top of the first, something like this

[image]
 .

I've found in the docs how to rotate (MarvinImage.rotate) but i haven't found a method that can append the 2 images.

Also, any suggestions of other libraries that can do this is also greatly appreciated. What I've tried until now:

- BufferedImage and ImageIO: takes a whole lot of memory, would probably work if the write would work (JPEGImageWriter basically complains about the image being too big - integer overflow)
- ImageMagick and im4java - works but terribly slow (13 minutes and 100% disk usage)

Thanks!

Bogdan

Answer (score 2):

[libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) can do this quickly and in little memory, but unfortunately there's no convenient Java binding. You'd need to write a few lines using something like [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) and then shell out to that.

For example:

```
import sys
import pyvips

one = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])
two = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[2], access='sequential')
one.rot180().join(two, 'vertical').write_to_file(sys.argv[3])
```

The `access=` hint on [`new_from_file`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/VipsImage.html#vips-image-new-from-file) in `two` means we plan to read the second image top-to-bottom, ie. in the same order that pixels appear in the jpg file. This will let libvips stream that image, so it can overlap the decode of `two` with the write of the output image.

On this 2015 laptop, I see:

```
$ vipsheader ~/pics/top.jpg ~/pics/bot.jpg
/home/john/pics/top.jpg: 16000x24000 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, jpegload
/home/john/pics/bot.jpg: 16000x24000 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, jpegload
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./join.py ~/pics/top.jpg ~/pics/bot.jpg x.jpg
115236:27.85
$ vipsheader x.jpg 
x.jpg: 16000x48000 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, jpegload
```

So a peak of 115MB of memory, and it runs in 28s of real time.

That will create a temporary file for `one` so it can do the rotate. If you are OK using a lot of memory, you can try:

```
one = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[2], memory=True)
```

That will force libvips to open via a memory area. I now see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./join.py ~/pics/top.jpg ~/pics/bot.jpg x.jpg
1216812:14.53
```

Only 15s of real time, but a painful 1.2GB peak memory use.

Answer (score 0):

In ImageMagick 6, that is easy to do.

Input 1 (lena.jpg):

[image]

Input 2 (mandril3.jpg):

[image]

Unix Syntax:

```
convert lena.jpg \( mandril3.jpg -rotate 180 \) +swap -append result.jpg
```

[image]

For Windows syntax, remove the \s. For ImageMagick 7, replace convert with magick.

ImageMagick comes with Linux distributions. It is also available for Mac OSX and Windows.